# Zero free regions of Riemann's zeta function

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Is there a constant $c<1$ such that Riemann's $\zeta$ function is *known* not to vanish for $\Re s \geq c$ (i.e. real part at least $c$)?

My feeling is that the answer is "no", but I could not find a clear statement of this on the web or in books.

(any other enlightening basic information about the state of knowledge about zero free regions would be appreciated)

Comment: I thought someone had proved that non-trivial zeros must lie in the critical strip? $0 \le Re(z) \le 1$?

Comment: @SEWillB: Yes. That's correct. My question is whether anyone was able to shrink this strip even a bit, using a vertical line to the left or $Re(z)=1$.

Comment: No, this is a notorious unsolved problem.

Comment: Oh sorry! Didn't see $c \lt 1$! My bad, I don't know of any such result

Comment: There are some results of the form $\zeta(\sigma + it)\not =0$ for $\sigma > f(t)$ on the critical strip, but the bound approaches $1$ fairly quickly.